# JavaScript Arrow Function and Closure problem

Tags: javascript, closures, arrow-functions

I'm working on Lambda Expression in Javascript and I wrote the following code:

```
var succRender = (x) => 'succ('+ x + ')';
var numerify = expr => ((expr)(succRender) (0));
var ZERO = f => x => (x) ;
var ONE  = f => x => (f(x)); 
var TWO = f => x => (f(f(x))); 
var THREE = f => x => (f(f(f(x))));
var PLUS = n => m => f => z => (n(f) (m(f)(z))) ;
```

When I call:

```
console.log(numerify((PLUS) (TWO) (THREE)));
```

the console replies correctly

```
succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))
```

But I've called:

```
console.log(numerify((PLUS) (TWO) (THREE)));
```

and

```
var PLUS = n => m => f => z => (n(f) (m(f)(z))) ;
```

has four parameters....
How Javascript really works to perform this situation? Which are the "values" of f and z in the call? And how Javascript retrieves those value two complete the task?

thanks in advance

Ed

Comment: Wow, that's `functionCallCeption`! `:)`

Comment: You won't get values for `f` or `z`. Not *yet*, at least - you would get back a function that is essentially going to be `f => z => (TWO(f) (THREE(f)(z))) ;`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed how you're calling the function: calling `(PLUS) (TWO) (THREE)` returns you a function with two of the four parameters "set" and `numerify` passes two extra parameters - `f = succRender` and `z = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Lets evaluate it step by step:

```
  PLUS(TWO)
```

that calls the first function and passes `TWO` as `n`, it evaluates to:

```
 m => f => z => (n(f) (m(f)(z)))
```

Then that is called with `(THREE)`, so `m` is `THREE`, it evaluates to:

```
 f => z => (n(f) (m(f)(z)))
```

Now `numerify(...)` gets called with `expr` being the line above, and inside the function it is:

```
 expr(succRender)(0)
```

So it calls the function with `f` being `succRender` and `z` being `0`. Now we can evaluate the PLUS body, so this:

```
  n(f) (m(f)(z))
```

becomes:

```
  TWO(succRender) (THREE(succRender)(0))
```

Now the `TWO` call gets evaluated, with `succRender` being `f` and the line above results in

```
 (x => (f(f(x)))) (THREE(succRender)(0))
```

The same happens with `THREE`:

```
 (x => f(f(x)))) ((x => (f(f(f(x)))))(0))
```

Now the right arrow function gets evaluated as ut gets called with `(0)` so `x` is `0`

```
 (x => f(f(x))) (f(f(f(0))))
```

So now `succRender` (`f`) gets called three times with the redult of the previous call:

```
 (x => f(f(x))) ("succ(succ(succ(0)))")
```

Now the last arrow function gets evaluated and `succRender` gets called two times again:

```
 "succ(succ(succ(succ(succ(0)))))"
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's unpack things a bit to see what is happening more clearly. I've re-written `PLUS` as a simpler function that still takes four parameters but just adds them together.

```js
var PLUS = a => b => c => d => a + b + c + d;

var intermediateResult = (PLUS)(1)(2); //the parenthesis around PLUS are actually not needed
console.log("intermediateResult", intermediateResult);

var secondIntermediateResult = intermediateResult(3);
console.log("secondIntermediateResult", secondIntermediateResult);

var finalResult = intermediateResult(3)(4);
console.log("finalResult", finalResult);
```

As you can see, if you only pass the first two parameters, you get a function back. You need to "fill in" all values in order to get the result.

---

Now, let's break down what happens in your code:

```
(PLUS) (TWO) (THREE)
```

As I mentioned, the parenthesis around `PLUS` are not needed. They don't do anything. So I'll re-write what's happening here:

```
var firstIntermediateResult = PLUS(TWO);
var secondIntermediateResult = firstIntermediateResult(THREE);
```

---

So, you are passing the first two parameters.

```
numerify((PLUS) (TWO) (THREE))
```

If we substitute with the breakdown from before, this is equivalent to

```
numerify(secondIntermediateResult)
```

---

So, let's look at the `numerify` function:

```
var numerify = expr => ((expr)(succRender) (0));
```

it takes a parameter called `expr`, then passes `succRender` to it. This is another function but it doesn't matter in terms of understanding the call sequence. From above we see that will return another function that takes one final parameter before returning a result and that parameter is `0`, so re-written the result of your program is:

```
var thirdIntermediateResult = secondIntermediateResult(succRender);
var finalResult = thirdIntermediateResult(0);
```

---

So, the final form of `PLUS` after all arguments are supplied looks like this

```
n(f) (m(f)(z)) --> TWO(succRender)(THREE(succRender)(0))
```